# Missing Style Library and ContentQueryMain.xsl

Tags: style-library

I'm working on a Sharepoint farm has been stuffed and is missing the Style Library from the Site Collection.  I've tried deactivating/activating the Site Collection & Site features Server Publishing Infrastructure & Server Publishing but it makes no difference.

I can access the Style Library by browsing directly through the file structure, but it's missing ContentQueryMain.xsl from the XSL Style Sheets directory - which is caused content query web parts to crash.

Can anyone suggest a method of repair to get this stuff working properly??

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to shoe-horn a fix for this by creating a new site collection, and turning on Server Publishing Infrastructure.

Then I saved the Style Library from the new site collection as a template including content, and downloaded it.  Then I uploaded this to my stuffed site collection and created the Style Library from it.

This seems to have fixed my problems for the moment...  Hope this helps someone else.